# Array returning undefined when it should return something else?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, web, socket.io

I am struggling with query.. I've been searching a lot, the only relevant posts I found had no answers.

row[0] returns undefined, I can't seem to find out why..

info:

As mentioned, `logger.warn(rows[0])` returns `undefined`

`rows.length` returns `0`

`logger.warn(pool.escape(hash))` returns the correct hash(same as in DB)

`logger.warn(rows[0].hash)` returns `undefined`

This is the error in console/log file: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined`

```
socket.on('hash', function(hash) {
        query('SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `hash` = '+pool.escape(hash),
    function(err, rows) { 
            logger.warn(rows[0]) // returns "undefined"
            if((err) || (!rows.length)) return socket.disconnect();
    }
```

**EDIT: QUERY FUNCITON**

```
function query(sql, callback) {
if (typeof callback === 'undefined') {
    callback = function() {};
}
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if(err) return callback(err);
    logger.info('DB Connection ID: '+connection.threadId);
    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        connection.release();
        return callback(null, rows);
    });
});
```

}

**EDIT: Debug log**

https://gyazo.com/858796b81c674ba816f974039eea1c09

**EDIT: On disconnect**

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        logger.warn('Socket disconnect');
        io.sockets.emit('message', {
            type: 'logins',
            count: Object.size(io.sockets.connected)
        });
        delete users[user.email];
    })
```

Comment: what is hash? It seems like hash is undefined.

Comment: during broadcast of `hash` event,are u sending the hash?

Comment: `Hash` is defined, and returns the correct value. @Jiro90
**EDIT:** yes @RIYAJKHAN, I am, and that part is working fine.

Comment: What is `query`? Is `hash` numerical?

Comment: @robertklep, sorry, I didn't include that. Edited post now. Hash is an email address. `test@mail.com` returns `test%40mail.com`

Comment: @ZanderMøysal perhaps turn on [debugging](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#debugging-and-reporting-problems) and see if the query that's being sent to the database is correct (and also what the database is returning, if anything). Also, make sure that you release the connection even in case of errors.

Comment: @ZanderMøysal are the e-mail addresses stored in that URL-escaped fashion in the database?

Comment: As you can see, I am disconnecting on error with `if((err) || (!rows.length)) return socket.disconnect();` That's the problem.. A user logs in, then he disconnects instant.. instead of being logged in.. I edited the post with a screenshot of the debugging log. @robertklep

Comment: @ZanderMøysal are you using `mysql`, or another database/driver? Also, how exactly is the data stored in the database? Using `%40` or using `@`? I don't see the database queries being logged. And you're not calling `connection.release()` when `connection.query()` returns an error.

Comment: Im using `phpmyadmin`. The data is stored using `@`.  I updated post again. @robertklep

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with node, but wouldn't `hash` need to be quoted in the query if it isn't a numeric value? like `"SELECT * FROM members WHERE hash = '"+pool.escape(hash)+"'"`

Comment: Tried now.. Doesn't make a difference @JonathanKuhn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the log, it seems that the client is sending the hash event value like this: `test%40mail.com`.

However, as you state in your comment, in the database the value is stored as this: `test@mail.com`.

Which means that before running the query, you need to URI-unescape the hash value, and then SQL-escape it, before passing it to the database:

```
socket.on("hash", function(hash) {
  hash = pool.escape(decodeURIComponent(hash));
  query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `hash` = " + hash, function(err, rows) {
    ...
  });
});
```